# Why are eigenvectors of Matrices orthogonal to the vector 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

For transposes of Markov matrices we have eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ with eigenvector $\vec{1}$. According to my professor, all eigenvectors with eigenvalue other than 1 of the Markov matrix must be orthogonal to $\vec{1}$. Why is this the case?

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with Markov matrices. For every real square matrix $A$, if it has, over $\mathbb R$, a left eigenpair $(\mu,u)$ and a right eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$ and $\lambda\ne\mu$, then $u$ and $v$ must be mutually orthogonal, i.e., $u^Tv=0$, because $\mu u^Tv=(u^TA)v=u^TAv=u^T(Av)=\lambda u^Tv$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sum of each column in a Markov matrix $M$ is $1$.

So ${\bf1}^TM={\bf1}^T$.

If $M{\bf v}=\lambda{\bf v}$ then
$${\bf1}^T{\bf v}={\bf1}^TM{\bf v}={\bf1}^T\lambda{\bf v}\ .$$
If $\lambda\ne1$ then ${\bf1}^T{\bf v}=0$. that is, ${\bf1}\cdot{\bf v}=0$.